# admob positioned in the middle of the screen?

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I have a positioning issue of admob for the ipad. The position of the banner is in the middle of the screen when running on ipad.  Android and iphone display the banner on the bottom.  After debuging     `CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];` seems to think its an iphone. Any idea why?[I am using this sample](https://app.box.com/s/7lsxp9u4lam2rym6i2x8)

Its a cocos2d project.

```
AppDelegate.h
#define ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID  ((IS_IPAD) ? @"a1526954f69b314"  : @"a1526955dc20272" );

#import "GADBannerView.h"
typedef enum _bannerType
{
    kBanner_Portrait_Top,
    kBanner_Portrait_Bottom,
    kBanner_Landscape_Top,
    kBanner_Landscape_Bottom,
}CocosBannerType;
#define BANNER_TYPE kBanner_Portrait_Bottom


@interface AppController : CCAppDelegate<GADBannerViewDelegate> {

    CocosBannerType mBannerType;
    GADBannerView *mBannerView;
    float on_x, on_y, off_x, off_y;}
-(void)hideBannerView;
-(void)showBannerView;

@end
AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppController

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Configure Cocos2d with the options set in SpriteBuilder
    NSString* configPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Published-iOS"]; // TODO: add support for Published-Android support
    configPath = [configPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"configCocos2d.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary* cocos2dSetup = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:configPath];

    // Note: this needs to happen before configureCCFileUtils is called, because we need apportable to correctly setup the screen scale factor.
#ifdef APPORTABLE
    if([cocos2dSetup[CCSetupScreenMode] isEqual:CCScreenModeFixed])
        [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenAspectFitEmulationMode];
    else
        [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenScaledAspectFitEmulationMode];
#endif

    // Configure CCFileUtils to work with SpriteBuilder
    [CCBReader configureCCFileUtils];

    // Do any extra configuration of Cocos2d here (the example line changes the pixel format for faster rendering, but with less colors)
    //[cocos2dSetup setObject:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 forKey:CCConfigPixelFormat];

    [self setupCocos2dWithOptions:cocos2dSetup];

#ifndef APPORTABLE

    [[AAGameCenter sharedGameCenter] authenticateLocalUser];
#endif
    [self createAdmobAds];


    return YES;


}


- (CCScene*) startScene
{
    return [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainMenuScene"];


}
+ (void)initialize
{

#ifndef APPORTABLE
    //configure iRate
    [iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID = 87522385224; // Replace this
#endif
}
-(void)createAdmobAds
{
    mBannerType = BANNER_TYPE;

    if(mBannerType <= kBanner_Portrait_Bottom)
        mBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    else
        mBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.

    mBannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-885995432323732999994/1885724261";


    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.

    mBannerView.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.navController.view addSubview:mBannerView];

    //#ifdef DEBUG
    //    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    //    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
    //#endif


    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [mBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

    CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;

    off_x = 0.0f;
    on_x = 0.0f;

    switch (mBannerType)
    {
        case kBanner_Portrait_Top:
        {
            off_y = -frame.size.height;
            on_y = 0.0f;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Portrait_Bottom:
        {
            off_y = s.height;
            on_y = s.height-frame.size.height;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Landscape_Top:
        {
            off_y = -frame.size.height;
            on_y = 0.0f;
        }
            break;
        case kBanner_Landscape_Bottom:
        {
            off_y = s.height;
            on_y = s.height-frame.size.height;
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    frame.origin.y = off_y;
    frame.origin.x = off_x;

    mBannerView.frame = frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];

    frame = mBannerView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = on_x;
    frame.origin.y = on_y;


    mBannerView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)showBannerView
{
    if (mBannerView)
    {
        //banner on bottom
        {
            CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
            frame.origin.y = off_y;
            frame.origin.x = on_x;
            mBannerView.frame = frame;


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                  delay:0.1
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
                 frame.origin.y = on_y;
                 frame.origin.x = on_x;

                 mBannerView.frame = frame;
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
             }];
        }
        //Banner on top
        //        {
        //            CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
        //            frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
        //            frame.origin.x = off_x;
        //            mBannerView.frame = frame;
        //
        //            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        //                                  delay:0.1
        //                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        //                             animations:^
        //             {
        //                 CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
        //                 frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
        //                 frame.origin.x = off_x;
        //                 mBannerView.frame = frame;
        //             }
        //                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
        //             {
        //
        //
        //             }];
        //        }

    }

}


-(void)hideBannerView
{
    if (mBannerView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
             frame.origin.y = off_y;
             frame.origin.x = off_x;
             mBannerView.frame = frame;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {


         }];
    }
}


-(void)dismissAdView
{
    if (mBannerView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

             CGRect frame = mBannerView.frame;
             frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height ;
             frame.origin.x = (s.width/2.0f - frame.size.width/2.0f);
             mBannerView.frame = frame;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [mBannerView setDelegate:nil];
             [mBannerView removeFromSuperview];
             mBannerView = nil;

         }];
    }

}


@end
```

Comment: downloaded sample and it shows banner in bottom, not in middle.

Comment: thats strange ive tested it on all ipads and its always in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation until I found this. @macgeo your solution does work, I am not sure why but it does revert back the size to the values that work for an ipad device

Additional info: Using SpriteBuilder with produces a content size of (384,512) on a portrait layout with a content scale factor of 4. The content scale factor has no influence in the result of the view positioning as when changing size to

```
CGRect contentFrame = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.bounds;
```

which produces a size of (768,1024) like if it were using a content scale factor of 2, but still the value is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Think problem might be fixed by changing viewSize to view.bounds

```
//CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
CGRect contentFrame = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.bounds;
```

And then using contentFrame.size.height for your y positioning. Was having trouble with iAd stuff and that seemed to fix it.